# How to delete a single item when button has clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a to-do list project and stuck at this part where when a trash button is clicked all the list items will be deleted and it won't add any new to-do items.

I've checked other posts but couldn't really find the answer for my project, please help!

```js
    let input = document.querySelector('#todo')
    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    let list = document.querySelector('#list');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let txt = input.value;
        if (txt === "") {
            alert('Please write something to do!');
        } else {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = txt;
            list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
            input.value = '';
    
            const delBtn = document.createElement("i");
            delBtn.classList.add("fas", "fa-trash-alt");
            li.appendChild(delBtn);
    
            delBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
                list.parentNode.removeChild(list);
            }) 
        }
    })
    
    
    list.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if(e.target.tagName == 'LI') {
            e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
        }
    })
```

```html
     <div class="todoList">
                <h1>To-do List</h1>
                <div class="add-element">
                    <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add new to-do">
                    <button id="btn">Add</button>
                </div>
        
                <div class="element-list">
                    <ul id="list"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `list.parentNode.removeChild(list);` deletes the entire list. Don't you want to delete just the `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.parentNode.removeChild(list);` deletes all the list, if you want to delete only one element from the list, add a  `button` to every `li` and change this line to `li.parentNode.removeChild(li);` like this:

```js
    let input = document.querySelector('#todo')
    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    let list = document.querySelector('#list');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let txt = input.value;
        if (txt === "") {
            alert('Please write something to do!');
        } else {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = txt;
            list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
            input.value = '';
    
            const delBtn = document.createElement("i");
            li.appendChild(delBtn);
    
            delBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
                li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
            }) 
        }
    })
    
    
    list.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if(e.target.tagName == 'LI') {
            e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
        }
    })
```

```html
     <div class="todoList">
                <h1>To-do List</h1>
                <div class="add-element">
                    <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add new to-do">
                    <button id="btn">Add</button>
                </div>
        
                <div class="element-list">
                    <ul id="list"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what he did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: And what I wanted was using an icon to delete the list item, so just replacing 'list.parentNode.removeChild(list);' to 'li.parentNode.removeChild(li);' worked perfectly!